# How to change data in column if its not equals to value in VIEW table?

Tags: sql-server, view

I have a VIEW table in MSSQL with a column that holds the user 'Status'

This VIEW table collected it's information from another Table.

In the Original Table , the User 'Status' contains 4 Status. 
A,X,S,T,B

Below is my create view script. With the create View Script , how do i put the condition "If Status != A , update Status to X " , so that whenever i run statement "Select * from view_table" , all user status != A is already X?

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Staff_List] AS
select
EMPLOYEE_BIODATA.EMPLOYEE_ID, 
EMPLOYEE_BIODATA.EMPLOYEE_NO, 
EMPLOYEE_BIODATA.EMPLOYEE_NAME, 
EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYMENT.EMPLOYEE_STATUS, 
EMPLOYEE_BIODATA.MEDIA_CONTACT3, 
NATIONAL_ID2,  
EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYMENT.BRANCH_CODE, 
EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYMENT.DEPARTMENT_CODE,
EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYMENT.DATE_RESIGNED    
FROM EMPLOYEE_BIODATA

LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYMENT    
on EMPLOYEE_BIODATA.EMPLOYEE_ID=EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYMENT.EMPLOYEE_ID
```

Comment: Unless the view be materialized, the result set obtained from a view is completely identical to what the underlying table already contains.

Comment: So basically i cant add an "If" condition in the create view script?

Comment: Just think of the view as a filter which sits on top of your table.  Do not worry about maintaining the view.

Comment: Just received the requirement from top that they needed the View Table to have Status that is not A is then changed to X whenever they run query "Select * from View_table"

Comment: @Alex - My Apologies. I wasnt paying attention on the formatting this time compared to my other questions.

Comment: Added my own answer. Managed to answer my own question. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple tries. I managed to answer my own questions. I added IIF(EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYMENT.EMPLOYEE_STATUS != 'A', 'X' , 'A' ) within the script.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Staff_List] AS
select
EMPLOYEE_BIODATA.EMPLOYEE_ID, 
EMPLOYEE_BIODATA.EMPLOYEE_NO, 
EMPLOYEE_BIODATA.EMPLOYEE_NAME, 
IIF(EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYMENT.EMPLOYEE_STATUS != 'A', 'X' , 'A' ), 
EMPLOYEE_BIODATA.MEDIA_CONTACT3, 
NATIONAL_ID2,  
EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYMENT.BRANCH_CODE, 
EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYMENT.DEPARTMENT_CODE,
EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYMENT.DATE_RESIGNED    
FROM EMPLOYEE_BIODATA

LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYMENT    
on EMPLOYEE_BIODATA.EMPLOYEE_ID=EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYMENT.EMPLOYEE_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Really good answer to your issue Mohd ! I usually use case to be flexible. IIF is perfect for your case. Don't forget you do a LEFT JOIN so it could be possible to have NULL for EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYMENT.EMPLOYEE_STATUS

```
select ... , 
case 
   when EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYMENT.EMPLOYEE_STATUS ='A' then 'A'
   WHEN EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYMENT.EMPLOYEE_STATUS IN ( 'X','S','T','B' ) then 'X'
   else 'ERROR'
end
...
FROM
```